# calling expensive queries multiple times vs. using cursors

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

Given a large list as the input parameter for an expensive query (a table valued function) I want to perform a couple of tests on each resultset of these function calls.

I was wondering, as I try to avoid the use of cursors whenever they are not needed, if the query optimizer really calls the Table Valued function every time I add another CASE WHEN to the query, or if it is caching the results in the following example query.

```
select Case
   when not exists (select * from expensive_tvf(list.parametervalue)) then 'does not exist'
   when list.x <> (select top 1 name from expensive_tvf(list.parametervalue)  order by order asc) then 'x does not match'
   when list.x not in (select name from expensive_tvf(list.parametervalue) then 'x is not contained'
 END as "TestMsg"
FROM InputTable list
```

In other words: Is it better to use an Cursor for this Kind of pattern or is this still something I can do in a single query in an effective manner?

---

EDIT: as @Larnu mentioned (Thx btw, upvote), I redesigned the query to make use of OUTER APPLY (I also want to test, if the tvf returns nothing)...

```
select case
   when list.x <> FIRST_VALUE(tvf.name) OVER (PARTITION BY list.parametervalue ORDER by tvf.order asc) THEN 'x does not match'
   when list.y <> LAST_VALUE(tvf.name) OVER (PARTITION BY list.parametervalue ORDER by tvf.order asc) THEN 'y does not match'
   when tvf.name IS NULL THEN 'function did not return values'
END as "TestMsg"
FROM InputTable list
OUTER APPLY (select name,order from expensive_tvf(list.parametervalue)) tvf
```

That seems to work but I am not quite sure if this is really more effective, as the queries runtime is still quite Long and I am afraid that the function isn't run only once per input row but twice or more often.

Comment: For your `CASE` expression, the tvf will be called for **every** expression that needs to be determined. So, if the first expression evaluates to true, then it will be called once (per row). ff none, or the 3rd evaluates to true, then it would be called 3 times (per row). So, say you have 1,000 rows returned from your table `InputTable`, then function `expensive_tvf` might be called up to 3,000 times. That is going to be incredibly costly. I would recommend you consider using `APPLY`.

Comment: @Larnu thx for the hint, didn't know what APPLY is actually useful for. Updated my Question

Comment: Thanks. Is the TVF an inline table-value function, or a multi-statement table-valued function? Would you be able to update your post with the DDL of it? Also, no need to use select. you can simply do: `OUTER APPLY dbo.expensive_tvf(list.parametervalue) tvf`. Once your posted the DDL for your function, comment and mention me again.

Comment: Tools like [Sql Server Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler) can help you understand how many times your function is called.

Comment: @Larnu Sorry, I am not able to post the full DDL of that function, it's a multi statement function, basically it`s a router which is sorting datasets along a graph structure in our database. One call of that function needs about 10 sec. to run. We have ~600 routes in this particular database. The script should test, which routes are not working as expected. But I am more interested in this problem pattern and if it is possible to solve that without Cursors. At the Moment I solve my particular problem in a procedural way as this is at least more readable and runs more responsive

Comment: @Enzin82 It's perfectly clear to me, that the function is called multiple times. I was wondering if there is an effective non-procedural way I dont't know yet, to prevent that unwanted behaviour or if I just should implement it in a procedural way.

Comment: Multi Statement Table-value functions aren't particularlly quick either, however, if you won't post the code that it runs, there's nothing else I can do. Not provided the function is akin to calling a garage and telling them your car isn't work properly; and when they ask you to take it to them you tell them they need to fix it over the phone. If I can see the SQL you're running, I can't help any more; other than to say use a inline table-value function, not a multi statement.